# The universal envelope U(L) is a PI-algebra iff L is abelian

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras

Let $k$ be a field with $\operatorname{char} k = 0$. Let $L$ be a Lie $k$-algebra. Then the universal envelope $U(L)$ is a PI-algebra iff $L$ is abelian.

Remark:
PI-algebra means polynomial identity algebra, an algebra that satisfies a nonzero polynomial.

Obviously, if $L$ is abelian, then $U(L)$ is commutative. But the reverse direction is difficult for me. I also know that this is a result in an article "Two remarks on PI-algebras, V.N.Latysev". But I can not find the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article is available [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=smj&paperid=4949&option_lang=eng), it seems that it hasn't been translated. The result you're interested in is Теорема 2; the proof is to notice that a non-abelian Lie algebra in characteristic zero contains as a subalgebra either a two-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebra or a three-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra, and their universal envelopings are not PI.

**UPD:** This only works for finite-dimensional Lie algebras.

Comment: But this fact (existence of a non-abelian 2-dimensional or 3-dimensional nonabelian subalgebra) is true for finite-dimensional non-abelian Lie algebras, but not in general. For instance, it fails for free Lie algebras.

Comment: @YCor That is true; the article only claims the result for finite-dimensional Lie algebras.

Comment: Actually, the result holds for arbitrary Lie algebras over fields of characteristic zero. This was noticed by Bahturin in his book "Identities on Lie algebras".